# Rebuild indexes based on fragmentation in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

So, i was looking on-line to find a solution for my problem, i am fairly new to the DBA thing so please don't be harsh on me :)

I have this piece of code which helps me rebuild indexes if they are fragmented to a certain percentage.
It has an IF condition for the Reorganize but i don't need it, i need to modify the code so it queries indexes of a certain database and schema and rebuilds only if the fragmentation is bigger than 5%.

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spKodyaz_Index_Maintenance]    Script Date: 19.11.2012 19:10:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[al]
(
    @DatabaseId smallint
)
AS

DECLARE
    @dbname sysname,
    @schema_name sysname,
    @object_id int,
    @object_name sysname,
    @index_name sysname,
    @avg_fragmentation float,
    @sql nvarchar(max)

CREATE TABLE ##tmpIndexMaintenance (
    object_schema_name sysname NULL,
    object_name sysname NULL,
    object_id int NULL,
    index_name sysname NULL,
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent float NULL
)

SET @dbname = DB_NAME(@DatabaseId);

SET @sql = N'USE [' + @dbname + '];
INSERT INTO ##tmpIndexMaintenance
SELECT
    object_schema_name(ps.object_id) as ObjectSchema,
    object_name(ps.object_id) as ObjectName,
    ps.object_id ObjectId,
    i.name as IndexName,
    ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM [' + @dbname + '].sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(' + CONVERT(nvarchar(5), @DatabaseId) + ', null, null, null, null) ps
inner join [' + @dbname + '].sys.indexes i
    on i.object_id = ps.object_id and i.index_id = ps.index_id
WHERE
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 5 -- reorganize and rebuild
    and ps.index_id > 0
ORDER BY avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC'

--print @sql
EXEC (@sql);

DECLARE indexFragmentation CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT * FROM ##tmpIndexMaintenance

OPEN indexFragmentation
FETCH NEXT FROM indexFragmentation INTO @schema_name, @object_name, @object_id, @index_name, @avg_fragmentation

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF @avg_fragmentation > 30 -- ReBuild index
        SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @dbname + ']; ALTER INDEX [' + @index_name +'] ON [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @object_name + '] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)';

    ELSE -- ReOrganize index
        SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @dbname + ']; ALTER INDEX [' + @index_name +'] ON [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @object_name + '] REORGANIZE';

    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC (@sql);

    FETCH NEXT FROM indexFragmentation INTO @schema_name, @object_name, @object_id, @index_name, @avg_fragmentation

END

CLOSE indexFragmentation
DEALLOCATE indexFragmentation

DROP TABLE ##tmpIndexMaintenance


GO
```

Comment: There's very little point in re-inventing the wheel when it comes to Index Maintenance. Ola Hallengren's script is pretty unbeatable and is likely to be meet all your needs. Download it, take a look and get an understanding of what it does and why. https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, thank you, but it looks a little to advanced for me right now

Answer (score 1):

The cursor already retrieves databases that are fragmented by more than 5%. Just remove the if condition and rebuild them by default

```html
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @dbname + ']; ALTER INDEX [' + @index_name +'] ON [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @object_name + '] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)';

    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC (@sql);

    FETCH NEXT FROM indexFragmentation INTO @schema_name, @object_name, @object_id, @index_name, @avg_fragmentation

END
```